# Looking for the documentation of the maven-glassfish-plugin

Tags: glassfish, maven

I've been looking all over for the documentation of the maven-glassfish-plugin:

```
<groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
```

Any hints where I could find it?

I want to which goals it has and what config options there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net

The source for the plugin is here: http://java.net/projects/maven-glassfish-plugin/sources/svn/show

Note: Due to the recent migration from CollabNet hosting to Oracle hosting with Kenai, the docs were off-line.  I just enabled the web site for the project.